# Pointers needed in debugging this query

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to debug this query without any success. IN the code below if I comment out the Pt.pt_id_nbr it works else the query keeps executing for a long time

```
Declare @sAlias         char(1),
 @sGQOrgId  char(3),
 @sID            char(12),
 @sType        char(1),
 @sSource    char(2),
 @dcLocationId numeric(18, 0) = NULL

 set @sAlias='N'
 set @sGQOrgId  =''
 Set @sID     =''
 Set @sType       ='M'
 Set @sSource  ='MD'

SELECT DISTINCT 
         '' 'ImportID',d.GQOrgId, d.DeviceId
        --,isnull(Pt.Pt_id_nbr,0)as Pt_id_nbr
        --,Pt.pt_id_nbr works if commented out else the query keeps executing for a long time
        , DeviceDesc = LTRIM(RTRIM(d.DeviceDesc)), d.Source, 
                      SourceDesc = LTRIM(RTRIM(s.SourceDesc))
        FROM    GasQuality.dbo.Device AS d WITH (NoLock)
        JOIN    GasQuality.dbo.SourceCodes AS s WITH (NoLock)
        ON      s.Source = d.Source
        left join elm_qa.elm.dbo.pt_sys_xref as Pt WITH (NoLock)
        ON    d.DeviceID = Pt.REF_VAL  and (Pt.OLD_SYS_ID = 'PK' and Pt.VAL_TYPE_CD = 'OM' ) 
        WHERE s.Type = @sType AND
            d.GQOrgId LIKE RTRIM(@sGQOrgId) + '%'
            AND d.Source LIKE RTRIM(@sSource) + '%'
            AND d.DeviceId LIKE RTRIM(@sID) + '%'

        ORDER BY d.GQOrgId, d.DeviceId, d.Source
```

Comment: look at the execution plans between the query that runs fast and the one that doesn't

Comment: I don't have permissions to look at the execution path

Answer (score 0):

Then I would try it as a group by rather than a distinct.